# Performing multiple injections with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How come the sessionFactory is not being injected to EventService class? What I am trying to do is to inject the sessionFactory to a  EventService class but what's happening is that it is only being injected inside Services class

My Application context xml

```
<!-- Inject my business services class to the action -->
    <bean id="services" class ="services.Services" scope ="singleton">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean  id ="eventservice" class ="services.EventServices" scope ="singleton">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

What am I missing here? am I not allowed to declare multiple injections?

Here is my EventServices class

```
package services;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import data.*;
import java.util.List;

// This class is the business services tier in the application.
// @Transactional is needed so that a Hibernate transaction is set up,
//  otherwise updates won't have an affect
@Transactional
public class EventServices {
    // So Spring can inject the session factory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory value) {
        sessionFactory = value;
    }

    // Shortcut for sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    public Session sess() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return sess().createQuery("from Event").list();
    }
}
```

and here is my Services class

```
package services;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import data.*;
import java.util.List;

// This class is the business services tier in the application.
// @Transactional is needed so that a Hibernate transaction is set up,
//  otherwise updates won't have an affect
@Transactional
public class Services {
    // So Spring can inject the session factory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory value) {
        sessionFactory = value;
    }

    // Shortcut for sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    public Session sess() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void createPerson(String name) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName(name);
        sess().save(p);
    }   

}
```

As of now it looks like a mediocre code, but I am going to fix this as soon as the EventServices finally worked

Comment: Does your `EventService` class have a setter for `sessionFactory`?

Comment: Yup, I have included it.

Comment: Can you include the Services and EventService files as well? are they related through inheritance?

Comment: You may want to enable spring logs by configuring the log4j level of `org.springframework.beans` package to DEBUG and see if sessionFactory is getting injected into EventServices. Also, how do you come to know that it is not getting injected? i.e are you getting NPE somewhere, if so where?

Comment: How to know if sessionFactory is getting injected into EventServices? is there any guide?

Comment: Your question says "What I am trying to do is to inject the sessionFactory to a EventService class but what's happening is that it is only being injected inside Services class". How did you know it is only getting injected in Services class and not in EventService class?